# Windows 10 shuts down after being in sleep mode overnight

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, shutdown, power-management

After my computer being to sleep mode over a long time ( 3 or 4 hours ) it shutdown automatically, I have not had this problem when putting my computer in sleep mode during the day and then waking it.
is there any way to extend the time of sleep, or to make it never shutdown ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try running Power troubleshooter and check if it helps.

1. Press Windows + X keys on the keyboard and select Control Panel.
2. Type Troubleshooting in the search bar on the Control Panel.
3. Click on View all on the left navigation pane. Click on Power.
4. Click on Advanced on the power troubleshooter dialog box and click on Run as administrator (Enter the credentials if required).
5. Click on Next and follow onscreen instruction complete the Power troubleshooter.

In addition, go to Control Panel-> Power Options-> Change plan settings-> Change advanced power settings ->  Sleep -> Hibernate after -> here put both "never".

Comment: The UI seems to have changed. In step 4, after clicking on Advanced, I don't see an option "Run as administrator".

Comment: Keep in mind that Power Troubleshooter resets some settings you have customized (for example when display goes off etc)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean hibernation mode (so it did not "shut down" completely)

Goto System settings -> Hardware and Sound -> Energy option

There you can set after how many minutes the computer goes into hibernation mode and sleep mode. Change the time for hibernation.

Comment: I did that. i want to know should i restart the computer to make those changes working ? because i shouldn't turn off the computer duo a BIOS problem.

Comment: @Ayoubk No, it should work without restarting

Comment: Why do you assume that? Mine shuts down completely (all programs are closed, and every unsaved bit is lost).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by going to: Control Panel->Power Options->Change plan settings->Change advanced power settings

In the dialog box that appears, then follow this: -
Sleep->Hibernate after-> set both options to Never

Answer (score 0):

My solution to "Win10 laptop will eventually shut down while asleep..."
was determined by the 'Turn off hard disk after [timeout] minutes' setting
which is found under the 'Advanced Settings' tab of 'Power Settings'.
I changed the setting to '9999' minutes which is roughly 7 days
and the laptop now reliably wakes up from sleep.
I assume that if the laptop is asleep for 7 days it will shut down.
This was the last change I made after updating all drivers.
I hope this helps y'all.

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?

Comment: @Toto I tried the accepted answer and the suggested troubleshooting fix was to revert to Balanced rather than Performance modes. This doesn't help as those settings can be changed themselves. I don't agree with the accepted answer as Windows troubleshooting is rarely of any help. Setting the harddrive to never turn off worked for me, but just to add, if you lower the timeout past 0, it will go to "never" which should be the default for anyone with SSDs.